# Laravel Class App\Http\Composers\MainComposer does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm new in laravel and i need some help with laravel 5, why is this erro? the error is in  Composer class and ComposerServiceProvider
[image]

MainComposer class

```
<?php
namespace App\Htt\Composers;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use App\Category;


class MainComposer {
    public function compose(View $view){
        $view->with('categories', Category::all());
    }
}
```

---

ComposerServiceProvider.php

```
 <?php
namespace App\Providers;
use View; // its saing class View does not exist
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{
    public function boot(){
        View::composer('*', 'App\Http\Composers\MainComposer');
    }

    public function register(){

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Try "use \View;" and it should works

Comment: Also this: View::composer('*', '\App\Http\Composers\MainComposer');

Comment: Your namespace should be App\Http\Composers, and Your MainComposer.php file should be in App/Composers/MainComposer.php